# Third point on ROC curve for Zero-R classifier in WEKA

Tags: machine-learning, weka, roc

I was comparing several classifiers in Weka and included a Zero-R as a baseline result. Because some of the classifiers had interesting ROC curves I also looked at those. However, I'm confused by the result I get with Zero-R (for which an ROC curve isn't very useful, I know)

My dataset has 122 true and 68 false instances, leading to a zero-r prediction of 64.2% true for every instance. Using a threshold of >=0% you then get TPR=122/122=1 and FPR=68/68=1. Using a threshold of >=100% you get TRP=0/122=0, FPR=0/68=0. This should lead to an AUC of 0.5.

So far, everything makes sense.

However, weka draws a third point at threshold 0.64162 (still smaller than 122/(122+68)=0.64211) for which it decides there are 96 true positives and 56 false positives. It then calculates an AUC of 0.4817.

Does anyone know where this third point comes from?